# Pymongo db.command options

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I just have a very general question db.command option supported by pymongo.

In the [doc](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=command#pymongo.database.Database.command), it is sayed that db.command accept str or dict of a mongo command, but no details of wich exactly are already implemented.

I know for example that mongoexport is not supported and has to be called outside python in bash basically. So it requires to use subcommand to reintegrate the mongo export inside my python programm.

So I'm just asking here to have a more complete outlook of db.command possibilities already implemented in Pymongo API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: mongoexport is an external program and not a "db.command option". You can execute external programs from Python, but your question is not very clear in it's purpose.

Comment: If I want to write a full ocm for mongo in python, I would like to fully integrate inside my python script the commands of mongo without having to call an external process

Comment: Well the basic thing about all mongo drivers is that just about "everything" is actually an extension on `db.command`. It truly is. So think even of basic "find", "update", "insert", "delete" CRUD operations as actually just invoking `db.command` behind the scenes. But "mongoimport" is not one of those operations and is an external utility that does "many" of those things like an external program should. Understand the difference now? Your ask is much broader than you think.

Comment: Yes I know that it's a large question, that's precisely. If pymongo runs already a dbcommand why should I run another external command for import. But it's ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pymongo db.command is similar to mongo shell [db.runCommand()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) method. 
You can the list of supported commands here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/

Comment: Precisely that's my question. For example export is not well ported.

Comment: mongoexport and mongoimport are not part of mongo shell as they are separate components